# Store and render Laravel blade templates from the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How can I render Blade templates from the database (instead of using a blade template file)?

I've checked this [Render template from blade template in database](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/render-template-from-blade-template-in-database/replies/175518) but for some reason is not replacing the variables in the template. It's giving a Notice: Undefined Variable.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the purpose of this?

Comment: Check out this package https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler

Comment: @Kyslik: Allow people to manage the email contents. If the blade templates are stored in the database, they will be able to change the contents without a developer

Comment: @TJistooshort did you find any good solutions? https://shopify.github.io/liquid/ looks good but it's for R&R , PHP one outdated to the max

Answer (score 3):

For these, who stumble across this just now: In Laravel 9, it's implemented natively.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
 
return Blade::render('Hello, {{ $name }}', ['name' => 'Julian Bashir']);
```

Answer (score 2):

One simplest approach would be to store the content in a temp blade file and render that.

Let's say we fetch this blade string stored in the DB:

```
$content_from_db = "Hello {{ $user_name }} This is your message";
```

Process:

```
$filename = hash('sha1', $content_from_db);

// temp file location where this file will be uploaded
// it can easily be cleared with 'php artisan view:clear'
$file_location = storage_path('framework/views/');

// filepath with filename
$filepath = storage_path('framework/views/'.$filename.'.blade.php');

file_put_contents($filepath, $content_from_db);

// add framework location so that it won't look into resource/*
view()->addLocation($file_location);

$data = [ 'user_name' => 'John Doe' ];

$rendered_content = view($filename, $data)->render();

$rendered_content = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $rendered_content));
```